# In natural disasters: died or killed?

Tags: word-usage

What is appropriate to use in cases of death in natural disasters: *killed*, or *died*?

Lets say, I wanted to say, "Earth destroyed this morning, everyone [died|got killed] in a parallel universe."

I am not sure what is more appropriate to use.

*Died* seems to me as if someone died from injury, or disease or something that does not intend to kill it. While *killed* seems more like an external factor that caused the death of someone purposefully.

Comment: Or, `Everyone perished.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **[kill](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kill)**, *verb:* To put to death; to deprive of life. *The Black Death was a disease that killed millions.*

You can be killed by an earthquake, by a building collapse, by drowning, or by a heart attack. Intent and purpose have nothing to do with it. Anything that causes you to die is something that kills you. Haven't you heard the warning, "[Smoking kills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobacco_packaging_warning_messages)"?

The only difference I can think of between "to die" and "to be killed" is that the latter carries a connotation that the death was somehow violent or unnatural.

> "My grandfather was killed by old age! In his *sleep!*" (??)

Answer (score 3):

Either *everyone died* or *everyone was killed* works pretty much equally well:

- Earth was destroyed this morning: everyone died in a parallel universe.
- Earth was destroyed this morning: everyone was killed in a parallel universe.

However, *got killed* sounds informal, so you probably wouldn’t use it in formal writing except as related speech.

Answer (score -2):

"Died" is to lose one's life due to injuries sustained or to natural causes from within.
"Killed" is to lose one's life due to an outside force or act of another.

Comment: You can have people who were killed by the floods, (an external force) who died in the floods (drowned) , or who lost their lives in the floods. Basically, you're saying there is no difference between the two.

Comment: "Died" seems to refer to any loss of life, whether disease, old age, murder, accident, or suicide.